# Get Unique list of Projects in Store

Tags: rally

Is it possible to query a unique list of Project values within an existing Store?  Is seems like the Collect method works with string values, but the Project field is an object value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you used lodash yet?  It's included in the SDK as a dependency and it's awesome for manipulating data.  You can read more about it here:

https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/#!/guide/third_party_libs-section-lo-dash-2.4.1

Here we can use _.map and _.uniq to get the desired result:

```
var projectNames = _.map(store.getRange(), function(record) {
    return record.get('Project').Name; //or ref, or objectid, etc...
}),
    uniqueProjectNames = _.uniq(projectNames);
```

Comment: I have not used lodash yet, but I will certainly get up-to-speed now.  Thanks for the swift and effective feedback!